# UICollectionView - How to add "PAGING" in UICollectionView scrolling with vertically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have implemented UICollectionView with the vertical scrolling and paging, first image showing properly but after scrolling layout get changed.

Code -

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

I enable the paging from UICollectionView

Also attached images below.

[image: First image showing properly but see the image second]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls check below screen sort setting of collectionview into storyboard.

- Estimate size none
- others min spacing for cells & for lines are zero or not

[image]